# Replicating React useState on Vanilla Javascript/Node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to get back the state value from this useState Vanilla JS replica:

```
let callIndex = -1

const stateValues = []

const useState = (initialValue) => {
    callIndex++ // 0

    const currentCallIndex = Number(callIndex) // 0

    if (stateValues[currentCallIndex] === undefined){
        stateValues[currentCallIndex] = initialValue
    }

    const setValue = (newValue) => {
        stateValues[currentCallIndex] = newValue
    }

    return [stateValues[currentCallIndex], setValue]
}

const [countA, setCountA] = useState(1)
const [countB, setCountB] = useState(-1)
```

This useState() function returns an initializing value and storing it in the stateValues array. But it doesn't actually refer to the array position.

```
setCountA(3)
// LOGs->   stateValues[0]:  3, stateValues[1]:  -1,  countA:  1,  countB:  -1
setCountA(5)
setCountB(9)
// LOGs->    stateValues[0]:  5, stateValues[1]:  9,  countA:  1,  countB:  -1
setCountA(2)
setCountB(5)
// LOGs->   stateValues[0]:  2, stateValues[1]:  5,  countA:  1,  countB:  -1
```

Now, I can make useState return an arrow function that returns stateValues[currentCallIndex] but then I have to call a function every time I need a state value.

Is there a more Reactsy way of returning the updated value by reference (countA rather than countA() )?

Comment: FYI this isn't really a replica without something observing and reacting to state changes, you're just using closures to store values.

Comment: As mentioned above, in React (as its name suggests) this "magic" happens because state updates trigger a rerun of the component function.

Comment: So is it still worth using this method in Javascript? I'm coding a multiplayer version of the TicTacToe from the React documentation and I moved all the game logic to the server. So my goal is to keep track of the changes with something resembling the useState behaviour

Comment: IMHO, this kind of order-dependant way of managing state is an overkill outside of React hooks.

Comment: @varChar16 I wouldn't homebrew state management; there are a variety of solutions applicable on the server side. On the server side you have to track whose state is being updated as well as the state.

Comment: @varChar16 "[...] the same as Redux" may or may not be what you actually want. There are state management solutions that may fit your needs; I'd just search for "nodejs state management" (recommendations are off-topic). I'd also add that this is explicitly **not** for React in the question rather than in a comment since it's tagged w/ React. The requirements are different on the server side--client-side has fewer concerns.

Comment: On the backend you're usually dealing with entities with unique identifiers, for example, users. One trivial way of managing states for these entities is an in-memory map between entity id and its state. To simplify state management you can use in-memory databases. And to push it further, you'll need to use an actual DB where data can be persisted between server restarts. You can start by looking at SQLite or MongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on doing it the React way without implementing an actual component lifecycle logic, you can do something like this:

```js
let callIndex = -1

const states = []

const useState = (initialValue) => {
    const currentCallIndex = callIndex++

    states[currentCallIndex] = states[currentCallIndex] ?? {
      value: initialValue,
      setValue: (newValue) => {
        states[currentCallIndex].value = newValue;
      },
    }

    return states[currentCallIndex]
}

let stateA = useState(1)
let stateB = useState(-1)

console.log(stateA.value, stateB.value) // 1, -1

stateA.setValue(2)
stateB.setValue(3)

console.log(stateA.value, stateB.value) // 2, 3

// ======= now let's reset the index =======
callIndex = -1;

// ======= and check that the state is persistent =======
stateA = useState(1)
stateB = useState(-1)

console.log(stateA.value, stateB.value) // 2, 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, You're right, I hadn't consider the influence of the component lifecycle like you and timotgl said. In the original video where I saw this code (youtube.com/watch?v=_qkX3yAmgEw) the creator used React logic to watch and update it.